# POST request 400 Bad Request in background.js of Chrome Extension for gmail

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

Building a Chrome Extension, trying to create a new label via the [users.labels:create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create) method. I successfully retrieve the access torken, permissions I believe are set appropriately yet I still get 400, and otherwise I can't find much else on the subject though I suspect I'm missing something pretty obvious.

(In case my code doesn't give it away this is my first web project, so any help is sincerely appreciated, and I am grateful for your time.)

## **background.js**

```
var postRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?access_token=" + accessToken;



$.ajax({
              url: postRequestUrl,
              method: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: {
                name: "posting test label",
                labelListVisibility: "labelShow",
                messageListVisibility: "show"
              }
            }).done(function(msg){
              alert("Success?")
            })
```

## **Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "key": "redacted>",
  "name": "<redacted>",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "0.0.2.0",
  "default locale": "en",
  "icons": { "128": "imgs/pledge_pin.png"},
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/mail/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/compose.js", "bower_components/jqnotifybar/jquery.notifyBar.js"],
      "css": ["css/stylesheet.css", "bower_components/jqnotifybar/css/jquery.notifyBar.css"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js", "js/jquery.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/*"
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<redacted>",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels"]
  }
}
```

## **Full Error Message**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?access_token=<token redacted> 400 (Bad Request)

    n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send   @   jquery.js:4
n.extend.ajax   @   jquery.js:4
(anonymous function)    @   background.js:106
propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)   @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
EventImpl.dispatchToListener    @   extensions::event_bindings:395
propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)   @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @   extensions::utils:94
EventImpl.dispatch_ @   extensions::event_bindings:379
EventImpl.dispatch  @   extensions::event_bindings:401
propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)   @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @   extensions::utils:94
messageListener @   extensions::messaging:188
propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)   @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
EventImpl.dispatchToListener    @   extensions::event_bindings:395
propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)   @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @   extensions::utils:94
EventImpl.dispatch_ @   extensions::event_bindings:379
EventImpl.dispatch  @   extensions::event_bindings:401
propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)   @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @   extensions::utils:94
dispatchOnMessage   @   extensions::messaging:316
```

Comment: I don't think you are far off. Could you write your entire error message?

Comment: Have you tried it in OAuth Playground and see if it shows the same error message there?

Comment: @Tholle Entire error message edited into post above.

Comment: @Sid I have not! Did not know it existed. Just tried and the URL I supply works when I subtract "access_token=<token>", which makes me wonder if perhaps for a POST I should be using something other than "access_token". I'll experiment a bit. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DanKlos As a general rule, do not change the post to another problem after an existing answer helped you, switching problem X to a problem Y. This invalidates the answer, which happened in case of Furhan's answer.

Comment: @DanKlos You still have to stringify the data :)

Comment: @Xan thank you for the advice both coding and StackOverflow etiquette, I'm new to this and answer invalidation is something that hadn't occurred to me. I will be sure to observe this in the future. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten to give the content type of your request payload, which is JSON in this case. `application/json` will do the trick. Also, `userId: "me"` is not needed in the request payload, and you have to stringify your data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}",
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json", // Content type has to be specified.
  data: JSON.stringify({           // You have to stringify your data.
    name: "Example",               // userId: "me" is not needed.
    labelListVisibility: "labelShow",
    messageListVisibility: "show"
  }),
  success: function(msg){
    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
  },
  error: function(msg){
    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Just added that and still receive 400 Bad Request. I will update the post with the error message and code.

Comment: @DanKlos Now please compare your code to this answer again. You did not understand it.

Comment: @Xan I just caught my mistake. It was as above in my code I just pasted it into the wrong spot above, sorry.

Comment: @Tholle You probably should highlight your changes with comments in the code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your request URL. Update as below:

```
var postRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?access_token=" + accessToken;
```

Comment: More specifically you are missing the `=` after `?access_token`.

Comment: @Furhan you are right! Nice catch. However when I add "=" I get a 400 Bad Request instead. I will edit my post to reflect this.